# Laravels queue worker does not recognize the --memory parameter

Tags: php, laravel, queue, worker, memory-limit

I have a really resource consuming image converting process. Large images need to be created, tiled and so on.

Now if i try to create a new image (width: 3508, height: 4961) with `imagecreatetruecolor()` I'm running out of memory.

In this case the new image would need ca. 85 mB on top of already used 100 mB.

The `memory_limit` in my php.ini is set to 1G. I can confirm that from my controller via `ini_get('memory_limit')`.

But if i run the same command from my `Job`, i'm getting 128M.

I call my worker like this: `php artisan queue:work --sleep=3 --tries=3 --daemon --memory=1024 --queue=foobar`
so there should be enough memory.
I have also tried to change the default value in the `\Illuminate\Queue\Worker` class without success.

How is that possible, that there is always this 128M limit?

---

***EDIT:***

I know, i could just `ini_set`from inside my `Job`, but it feels not right. There must be a dumb mistake i made or something.